# View elements of 2D array via double pointer for debugging purposes

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, pointers, debugging

I've looked at similar posts for this type of question but have not yet been able to find a method that I can use in Xcode to view the values of a 2D array through a pointer.

Initially, I create a 2D array and populate it with values from a string, as such:

```
int** createArray(int rows, int columns, char* string) {
    int** array;

    // allocating memory for three rows
    array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));

    // allocating memory for three columns
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
    }

    /* some code to populate array */

    return array;
}
```

Then, these types of arrays are passed as parameters to other functions and new arrays are created to manipulate values, as such:

```
void misplacedTiles(int rows, int columns, int** initState, int** goalState) {
    int** tempState;
    int** bestState;

    // allocating memory for number of rows
    tempState = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    bestState = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));

    // allocating memory for number of columns
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) {
        tempState[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
        bestState[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char));
    }

    /* some code to manipulate arrays */

    printArray(rows, columns, tempState);
    printArray(rows, columns, bestState);    
}
```

I would like to see the values that are within the indices of the array, as I am debugging, but I can only see the memory address where this array points to:

- tempState = (int **) 0x100740500  0x0000000100740500
- *tempState = (int *) 0x100732f50  0x0000000100732f50
- **tempState = (int) 0

I created a separate function `printArray()` that prints the array to the console so that I can see the values as I am debugging, but I wanted to know if there is a method of seeing these values as I am fixing my code. Any feedback is greatly appreciated!